# Disable Autoload (via IE Helpbar Popup) of ActiveX Control

Tags: javascript, object, activex, popup

In IE 9, I have an ActiveX control loaded using an object tag, ie something like:

`<object id="ASDF" classid="CLSID:..." codebase="ASDF.cab##version=1,2,3,4"></object>`.

Unless this control has already been installed, on page load a help bar pops up asking if I want to install.  Is there a way to disable this?

I'd like for it to load the control if it's installed and do nothing if not.

Thanks

PS Any pointers to Javascript info re ActiveX controls and object tags would be appreciated, I can't seem to find much via Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the codebase attribute and it will display the innerText of the OBJECT tag instead of attempting to install the control when it isn't already installed on the system.

Comment: Without codebase the control will not be installed when the user comes for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the **version** of your control packed in CAB is the same as you wrote in object tag.

Also you can make sure that there are no CLSID mismatches, but most probably the problem is in version.